# Bootstrap color variables

Tags: bootstrap-5

I just started learning Bootstrap 5 this week and have minimal knowledge of CSS, so I'm still pretty ignorant on how most of it works. I successfully installed bootstrap using npm to a demo project, but I was wondering how one is to use the expanded color set in the _variable.scss file (blue-100, blue-200, blue-300, etc.). I was hoping I can do something along the lines what you can do with Tailwind like:

```
<body class="bg-gray-200">
```

...but it doesn't seem like it is that easy. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to use the SCSS and compile it.  In that case you can add your own variations just after the `@include "variables";` and `"utilities"`, like so:

```
// Configuration
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "utilities";
@import "your_own_cool_stuff";  // ** your file goes here

// Layout & components
@import "root";
// ... and so on
```

Then you need to append to the individual `$utilities` variable ... see [Utility API - Using the API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#using-the-api) in the BS5 docs ... like so:

```
// ** contents of your file

$your_awsome_colors = (
  "gray-100": #eee,
  "gray-200": #ddd
  // and so on...
) !default;

// use API to merge background-color

// stylelint-disable-next-line scss/dollar-variable-default
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "background-color": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "background-color"),
      (
        values: map-merge(
          map-get(map-get($utilities, "background-color"), "values"), $your_awsome_colors,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Finally these will get generated when the ..

```
// Utilities
@import "utilities/api";
```

..line is called in the SCSS.